# How can I uninstall a software named Rolimno

Tags: virus, uninstall

I recently noticed that there is an software in my computer which I think I have never installed it. It display advertisements. I tried to uninstall it but when I start uninstalling it, it takes very long time to uninstall. Is there any other way to uninstall it without installing third party "Uninstaller Software" such as Antivirus

Comment: No that's not same.

Answer (score 0):

Rolimno is a malware application, and can be removed using Malwarebytes Anti-Malware.

http://www.malwarebytes.org/free/

http://botcrawl.com/how-to-remove-rolimno/